# Cannot group multiple columns from XML

Tags: sql, xml, grouping, nodes

I have a query that returns Server Details that are held in a varchar(max) xml field in SQL
My issue is with the drive columns, a Server can have multiple drives but these are multiple child items under the server parent node in XML, I have used the CASE WHEN lines to separate the drives into columns, but each drive letter generates its own row, so a Server with 2 drives creates 2 rows

```
STName          STDescription           RTName          RTDescription               RTQty    RTCode NTName          NTDescription               NTPVLAN NTSVLAN NTDomain    NTRam   NTCpus  NTVMTemplate    NTSCOM  RTCode  Cdrive  Ddrive  Edrive  Fdrive  Gdrive
Basic Service   Single Server Service   Standard Server Basic server configuration  1        STD    Standard Server Basic server configuration  {{int}} NULL    {{primary}} 4       2       1NIC2012R2CLUST TRUE    STD     50      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Basic Service   Single Server Service   Standard Server Basic server configuration  1        STD    Standard Server Basic server configuration  {{int}} NULL    {{primary}} 4       2       1NIC2012R2CLUST TRUE    STD     NULL    20      NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I hope its a fairly simple job to adjust my code to place both drives on the same row?

```
STName          STDescription           RTName          RTDescription               RTQty    RTCode NTName          NTDescription               NTPVLAN NTSVLAN NTDomain    NTRam   NTCpus  NTVMTemplate    NTSCOM  RTCode  Cdrive  Ddrive  Edrive  Fdrive  Gdrive
Basic Service   Single Server Service   Standard Server Basic server configuration  1        STD    Standard Server Basic server configuration  {{int}} NULL    {{primary}} 4       2       1NIC2012R2CLUST TRUE    STD     50      20      NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This is my query

```
DECLARE @XML xml; SET @XML = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), TemplateXml )) FROM dbTemplates FOR XML AUTO, Root('ACME'))
SELECT
ST.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as STName,
ST.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as STDescription,
RT.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTName,
RT.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTDescription,
RT.C.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTQty,
RT.C.value('(Code/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTCode,
NT.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTName,
NT.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTDescription,
NT.C.value('(PrimaryVlan/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTPVLAN,
NT.C.value('(SecondaryVlan/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSVLAN,
NT.C.value('(Domain/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTDomain,
NT.C.value('(RamSize/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTRam,
NT.C.value('(CpuCores/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTCpus,
NT.C.value('(VmTemplate/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTVMTemplate,
NT.C.value('(ScomInstall/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSCOM,
NT.C.value('(SccmInstall/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSCCM,
CASE WHEN DP.C.value('(Letter/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'C' THEN DP.C.value('(Capacity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') END AS Cdrive,
CASE WHEN DP.C.value('(Letter/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'D' THEN DP.C.value('(Capacity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') END AS Ddrive,
CASE WHEN DP.C.value('(Letter/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'E' THEN DP.C.value('(Capacity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') END AS Edrive,
CASE WHEN DP.C.value('(Letter/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'F' THEN DP.C.value('(Capacity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') END AS Fdrive,
CASE WHEN DP.C.value('(Letter/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'G' THEN DP.C.value('(Capacity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') END AS Gdrive
from @XML.nodes('ACME/dbTemplates/ServiceTemplate') as ST(C)
outer apply ST.C.nodes('Roles') as RO(C)
outer apply RO.C.nodes('RoleTemplate') as RT(C)
outer apply RT.C.nodes('NodeTemplate') as NT(C)
outer apply NT.C.nodes('Drives') as DR(C)
outer apply DR.C.nodes('DriveParameter') as DP(C)
ORDER BY STName,RTName
```

Here is a section of the XML as requested

```
<ACME>
  <dbTemplates>
    <ServiceTemplate xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <TemplateId>3205ac97-6396-4acb-8f93-5704297f1bbc</TemplateId>
      <Name>Basic Service</Name>
      <Description>Single Server Service</Description>
      <Roles>
        <RoleTemplate>
          <TemplateId xsi:nil="true" />
          <Name>Standard Server</Name>
          <Description>Basic server configuration</Description>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Code>STD</Code>
          <NodeTemplate>
            <TemplateId xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name>Standard Server</Name>
            <Description>Basic server configuration</Description>
            <PrimaryVlan>{{int}}</PrimaryVlan>
            <Domain>{{primary}}</Domain>
            <RamSize>4</RamSize>
            <CpuCores>2</CpuCores>
            <Drives>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>C</Letter>
                <Capacity>50</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>D</Letter>
                <Capacity>20</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>E</Letter>
                <Capacity>50</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
            </Drives>
            <VmTemplate>1NIC2012R2CLUST</VmTemplate>
            <ScomInstall>True</ScomInstall>
            <SccmInstall>True</SccmInstall>
          </NodeTemplate>
        </RoleTemplate>
      </Roles>
    </ServiceTemplate>
  </dbTemplates>
</ACME>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `nodes()` on `<DriveParameter>` you get all of them row-wise. The advantage was, that you can deal with any number.

What you want is a *side-by-side* result. In this case you must know, which letters you expect and use them as `XQuery`-filter (and be aware, that `XQuery` is case sensitive. The following solution will work with capitalized letters only...

And one hint: It is simpler to read, if you call your `CROSS APPLY`s like `A(ST)`, `B(RO)`, `C(RT)` and so on. Then you can call `ST.value(...)` and avoid the repeated `.C.value` of your query...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<ACME>
  <dbTemplates>
    <ServiceTemplate xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <TemplateId>3205ac97-6396-4acb-8f93-5704297f1bbc</TemplateId>
      <Name>Basic Service</Name>
      <Description>Single Server Service</Description>
      <Roles>
        <RoleTemplate>
          <TemplateId xsi:nil="true" />
          <Name>Standard Server</Name>
          <Description>Basic server configuration</Description>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Code>STD</Code>
          <NodeTemplate>
            <TemplateId xsi:nil="true" />
            <Name>Standard Server</Name>
            <Description>Basic server configuration</Description>
            <PrimaryVlan>{{int}}</PrimaryVlan>
            <Domain>{{primary}}</Domain>
            <RamSize>4</RamSize>
            <CpuCores>2</CpuCores>
            <Drives>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>C</Letter>
                <Capacity>50</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>D</Letter>
                <Capacity>20</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
              <DriveParameter>
                <Letter>E</Letter>
                <Capacity>50</Capacity>
              </DriveParameter>
            </Drives>
            <VmTemplate>1NIC2012R2CLUST</VmTemplate>
            <ScomInstall>True</ScomInstall>
            <SccmInstall>True</SccmInstall>
          </NodeTemplate>
        </RoleTemplate>
      </Roles>
    </ServiceTemplate>
  </dbTemplates>
</ACME>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT
ST.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as STName,
ST.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as STDescription,
RT.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTName,
RT.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTDescription,
RT.C.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTQty,
RT.C.value('(Code/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as RTCode,
NT.C.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTName,
NT.C.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTDescription,
NT.C.value('(PrimaryVlan/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTPVLAN,
NT.C.value('(SecondaryVlan/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSVLAN,
NT.C.value('(Domain/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTDomain,
NT.C.value('(RamSize/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTRam,
NT.C.value('(CpuCores/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTCpus,
NT.C.value('(VmTemplate/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTVMTemplate,
NT.C.value('(ScomInstall/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSCOM,
NT.C.value('(SccmInstall/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NTSCCM,

NT.C.value('(Drives/DriveParameter[Letter="C"]/Capacity)[1]','int') AS CDrive,
NT.C.value('(Drives/DriveParameter[Letter="D"]/Capacity)[1]','int') AS DDrive,
NT.C.value('(Drives/DriveParameter[Letter="E"]/Capacity)[1]','int') AS EDrive,
NT.C.value('(Drives/DriveParameter[Letter="F"]/Capacity)[1]','int') AS FDrive,
NT.C.value('(Drives/DriveParameter[Letter="G"]/Capacity)[1]','int') AS GDrive

from @XML.nodes('ACME/dbTemplates/ServiceTemplate') as ST(C)
outer apply ST.C.nodes('Roles') as RO(C)
outer apply RO.C.nodes('RoleTemplate') as RT(C)
outer apply RT.C.nodes('NodeTemplate') as NT(C)
ORDER BY STName,RTName
```

Comment: Confirmed working, thank you very much
as for better ways to show code, always learning, in fact I had only gotten this far by hacking apart other pieces of code found all over the place